# Why both "sign up" and "log in" especially when both are the same link?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, header, anonymous-visitors

I just noticed that when not logged in, I have "sign up" and "log in" links on top:

> [image]

Not sure how long it's like this however both link to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login.

As I understand it's by design (?) two have to links with different words point to the same page, I think we better remove the "sign up" as it's just confusing. (unless it will point to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login#create-account which indeed give the user option to create new account in one step)

This happens on all sites, except Meta.

Comment: Welp, I think this has been answered. Some ninja editing there, Oded.

Comment: @Richard where?

Comment: Oded's 'by design' edit. Interfaces like that are actually quite common on other websites, IIRC Reddit is similar.

Comment: @Richard I asked "why" and still can't see any reasonable reason hence the feature request asking to remove "sign up". If Oded won't explain will flag so it's at least tagged correctly as [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: I've brought this up to Jeremy's attention, as he can give a better answer than a simple bydesign.

Comment: Presumably, new users will get confused when they can't find a 'sign up' link, and established users will feel weird if they don't have a 'log in' link.

Comment: @Hannele clicking "sign up" and landing on "log in" is more confusing and more severe as they will think something is broken.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd we are redesigning the landing page in the next couple of weeks, and it will be tabbed with sign up and login tabs

Comment: @Jeremy two tabs with the exact same contents?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not exactly the same. The copy will be slightly different.   There's just not much of a difference, actually. We decided against an onboarding process, so we really just need you to put your Google/Facebook login in or sign up for a stack exchange account...

Comment: @Jeremy well, as long as it's clear how to proceed I'm all for it, though "sign up" leading to login form is somewhat confusing .

Answer (score 8):

Having both 'sign up' and 'log in' can be less confusing to people new to the site. If someone has never signed up or registered for the site, 'log in' doesn't seem like the place to sign up for an account. But also, it would not be intuitive that 'sign up' is where to go to log in. So even though both links point to the same page, having both links at the top of the page solves more problems than it causes.

Comment: This is basically our thinking.

Comment: Disagree, unless the "sign up" will explain more clearly how to really sign up e.g. click "login with Stack Exchange" then click "click here to sign up" then fill your details. @JeremyTunnell no way to add such a message somehow?